# Как в Android Studio сделать неотслеживаемым git-отслеживаемый файл?

Tags: git, android-studio

В Android Studio файл ошибочно добавлен в качестве отслеживаемого git. Как сделать его неотслеживаемым?

Желательно обойтись графическими средствами Android 
Studio.

Comment: были ли эти файлы закоммичены хоть раз?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman насчет одного не уверена, а другой - точно нет

Comment: какого они цвета?

Comment: > Желательно обойтись графическими средствами Android Studio
 почему ? вы боитесь консоли ?

Comment: @zb Можно и в консоли

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Они голубые

Comment: git rm --cached pathToFile

Comment: @zb Важно, где при этом находишься (в какой директории)?

Comment: важно быть в директории проекта или в одной из поддиректорий

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9#Удаление-файлов

Comment: @zb файлы из голубых стали красными (а не серыми, как остальные неотслеживаемые), и все равно при коммите они есть, и их нужно отключать

Comment: @zb Ура. Помогло после того, как я их закоммитила. Можете оформить как ответ

Comment: @zb Спасибо Вам большое)))

Comment: если они голубые, то значит они закоммичены.

Answer (score 0):

Файлы добавленные в репозиторий можно удалить их из него следующим образом: **выбрали файл(ы) в окне Project**, затем в меню **Edit** -> **Delete** -> убрать метку у **Safe delete** -> **OK**. После этого изменения надо поместить в репозиторий: **VCS** -> **Git** -> **Commit directory...**.

Если вам все еще нужен это файл, то **Edit** -> **Undo Deleting file**, после этой операции файл будет "красным".

Comment: Моя проблема уже решилась в консоли с помощь zb.  Файл стал белым, как до моей ошибки.
 Пытаясь проверить верность Вашего решения, я не смогла найти соответствующих команд. Возможно, ответ верен. Прошу простить мою недогадливость)))

Comment: @iramm какую команду вы не нашли?